# How do I get an if else statement to Print in the Else Portion?

Tags: r, if-statement, printing

I am not very good at coding, I'm working in R so please bear with me. I did search a bit, but maybe I didn't look hard enough.

Is it possible to have an else portion of the if else statement do two things? Here's the whiteboard, with a function:

example.function <- function(n) {

If n is greater than 10, return 1.
Else, compute 3n+4 and print (3n+4)
}

Things I've tried:
I attempted to use && statement in the Else command, and I also attempted to define (for example) my 3n+4 as a variable z <- 3n+4 && print(z).

The Else part is the one I'm stuck on. I have a recursive function, and I would like it to print the value each step of the way.

Another example would be the factorial recursive function:

```
if (x == 0)    return (1)
else           return (x * recursive.factorial(x-1))
}
```

If I was to input recursive.factorial(4), how do I get it to print out 4,12,24,24 instead of 24? I don't even need them as separate lines, though that would be nice, I just need that string of numbers.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don’t know R, but can you not just write two statements in separate lines?

Comment: Well when I attempted to do this, it spit out the final result that number of steps :(

Comment: The downvotes are likely because this appears to be homework (i.e. something you should be figuring out yourself), rather than a question about programming. The community is divided on whether answering homework questions is a reasonable use of our time/skills (my position is that it's ok to ask for help, so I've provided an answer below); for further info see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Oh, I understand. It probably would be hard to determine this for yourself, but I've long since graduated haha. I'm working on a project aside of my work, and I have never had an official course in R, so I don't really have the resources to search for this information besides what I can find online. I certainly appreciate those who's taken the time out to help me with this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to figure out?

```
recursive.factorial <- function(x) {
  if (x == 0 || x > 10)
    return (1)
  else
    return (print(x * recursive.factorial(x-1)))
}
recursive.factorial(9)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 24
[1] 120
[1] 720
[1] 5040
[1] 40320
[1] 362880

recursive.factorial(13)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Yes, precisely! Thanks I greatly appreciate it. Just out of curiosity, what does the || x> 10 do for our code? (I haven't touched R in like 3 years :P )

Comment: It means "or" i.e. if x equals 0 or x is greater than 10, return 1.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, it seems that what you want is simply to make two or more actions inside an else statement. To do that you only have to use {}. For example:

```
my_function <- function(n) {
    if(n > 10) {
       result <- 1
    } else {
       result <- 3 * n + 4
       print(result)
    }
    result
}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, you guys are helping me nail down my question. So I attempted this with the recursive algorithm and it still only spits out the final result instead of the whole string of numbers: `recursive.factorial <- function(x) {
if (x == 0)    return(1)
else         { data_return<-return(x * recursive.factorial(x-1))
print(data_return)}
return(data_return)
}
recursive.factorial(4)
`

Answer (score -2):

one way for your example.function would be the following code.

Greetings

```
example.function <- function(n) 
{
 if(n > 10)
 {
   data_return <- 1
 }else{
   data_return <- 3*n+4
 }
  
  return(data_return)
}

example.function(1)
example.function(11)
```

Comment: I attempted this with the recursive function sequence, and it gave me the following: `> recursive.factorial <- function(x) {
+ if (x == 0)    data_return <-(1)
+ else          data_return<- return(x * recursive.factorial(x-1))
+ return(data_return)
+ }
> recursive.factorial(4)
[1] 24
> 
` Did I do it wrong?